# How to get binary representation of window.location.href when href is a local file url?

Tags: javascript, html, binary, blob, arraybuffer

Is there any way to get the binary representation (Blob, ArrayBuffer, or something else) of the source HTML when window.location.href is a local file url?

This is simply an attempt to get a binary view of the original html file for various operations; I am not trying to load the html into itself.

This is readily accomplished by making a XmlHttpRequest to access the html as binary when the original is remote, but I know of no way to accomplish it if the original html is a local file.

Comment: Can you clarify? You're opening a local HTML file and you want to load the same file as a binary? Inside itself?

Comment: I've edited the original question in an attempt to clarify for you.